# Renaming a variable through a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having different files that have a variable that is named differently but has the same string character “type_category” e.g., type_category_lifestyle_characterstics, type_category_uniqueness etc. The idea is to go through these files and rename such variables to type_category. Below are examples of data frames

`df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), type_category_lifestyle_characterstics = c(5,6,7), rating = c(1,3,4))`

`df2 <- data.frame(id = c(9,5,3), type_category_uniqueness = c(4,6,1), rating = c(2,7,4))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for a "`data.table` only" solution (because of the tag)? are the data frames stored in a list?

Comment: I was open to either a dplyr or data.table solution

Comment: please upvote/ accept answers that the community knows the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the datasets in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')), ~ .x %>%
                rename_with(~ "type_category", 
      starts_with("type_category")))
```

-output

```
out
$df1
  id type_category rating
1  1             5      1
2  2             6      3
3  3             7      4

$df2
  id type_category rating
1  9             4      2
2  5             6      7
3  3             1      4
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your precious time and responding to my query

Answer (score 1):

We could use `setNames` with `lapply`:

```
my_list <- list(df1, df2)

colnames <- c("id","type_category","rating") 
lapply(my_list, setNames, colnames)
```

output:

```
[[1]]
  id type_category rating
1  1             5      1
2  2             6      3
3  3             7      4

[[2]]
  id type_category rating
1  9             4      2
2  5             6      7
3  3             1      4
```

Answer (score 0):

### Base R

Once you got them in a list, you can use `lapply` to change the variable names in all of them

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), type_category_lifestyle_characterstics = c(5,6,7), rating = c(1,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(9,5,3), type_category_uniqueness = c(4,6,1), rating = c(2,7,4))

lapply(list(df1, df2), 
       function(df){
         nms <- names(df)
         nms[grepl(pattern     = "type_category",
                   x           = nms,
                   ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "type_category"
         names(df) <- nms
         return(df)
       })
#> [[1]]
#>   id type_category rating
#> 1  1             5      1
#> 2  2             6      3
#> 3  3             7      4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   id type_category rating
#> 1  9             4      2
#> 2  5             6      7
#> 3  3             1      4
```

Just note that you would need to assign the result back to a list.

### data.table

Since you tagged `data.table`, this allows you to change the names in place and no extra assignment is necessary

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table::data.table(id = c(1,2,3), type_category_lifestyle_characterstics = c(5,6,7), rating = c(1,3,4))
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(id = c(9,5,3), type_category_uniqueness = c(4,6,1), rating = c(2,7,4))

invisible(
  lapply(list(dt1, dt2),
         function(dt){
           nms_old <- names(data.table::copy(dt))
           nms_new <- data.table::copy(nms_old)
           nms_new[grepl(pattern     = "type_category",
                         x           = nms_old,
                         ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "type_category"
           data.table::setnames(dt, old = nms_old, new = nms_new)
           return(NULL)
         })
)
dt1
#>    id type_category rating
#> 1:  1             5      1
#> 2:  2             6      3
#> 3:  3             7      4
dt2
#>    id type_category rating
#> 1:  9             4      2
#> 2:  5             6      7
#> 3:  3             1      4
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your precious time and responding to my query